# Select from a range of dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to select a range of dates where each date is one row?
What I would like to do is something like this pseudo code:

```
SELECT date from dual where date >= "2019-01-01" AND date <= "2019-01-05"
```

And results should be a single column with values:

```
2019-01-01
2019-01-02
2019-01-03
2019-01-04
2019-01-05
```

Is this even possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can do this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select '2019-01-01' dt
    union all select dt + interval 1 day from cte where dt < '2019-01-05'
)
select dt from cte order by dt
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cbc6e0fea1b90d908641e20885a3e51a)**:

```
| dt         |
| :--------- |
| 2019-01-01 |
| 2019-01-02 |
| 2019-01-03 |
| 2019-01-04 |
| 2019-01-05 |
```

---

In earlier versions, solutions would typically include a table of numbers, that contains sequential integers starting at 0.

```
create table mynumbers (n int);
insert into mynumbers values(1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

select '2019-01-01' + interval n day dt
from mynumbers n
where '2019-01-01' + interval n day <= '2019-01-05'
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b478a7dee92961fb82893ba2ba33e40)**

Note: if you need to generate a very large dataset, the "number table" solution is more efficient than the recursive query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like,

```
SELECT date from dual 
where date >= (SELECT min(a.date) from DatesTable a) 
AND date <= (SELECT max(b.date) from DatesTable b)
```

OR

```
    SELECT date from dual 
    where date BETWEEN  (SELECT min(a.date) from DatesTable a) 
                         AND 
                        (SELECT max(b.date) from DatesTable b)
```

You can also add some condition (by using WHERE clause) in the sub queries to reflect different situations.